# Website is unable to properly retrieve session information after PHP update

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I had some very simple code on a website to handle logins on the root of the site using ion_auth:

```
if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
   redirect("/login");
}
```

That page posts to /auth/login, which is handled by ion_auth. If the login is successful, the user is redirected to the root of the site. Otherwise, they go back to /login to try again. I initially thought I'd forgotten the password, but with a series of var_dump() calls, I found that the login is successful, but the call to $this->ion_auth->logged_in() returns false anyway.

All of this is after the host upgraded to PHP 7 - the code worked before. I've tried upgrading ion_auth, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were session related problems in early CI 3.x version, documented [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4830) and [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5118)

several session related issues were resolved in the latest versions, see the [change logs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/user_guide_src/source/changelog.rst)

**solution:** update to CI 3.1.7. (latest version as writing)

[Upgrading From a Previous Version](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html#upgrading-from-a-previous-version)