# Codeigniter 3 Sessions and RDS - Random Logouts

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, rds

Can someone explain or tell me if some kind of 'setting' in Codeigniter will solve this?

System : Amazon AWS EC2 (AWS Linux Centos 6.9)

Database : Amazon AWS RDS (Mysql Compatible 5.6.34)

Framework : Codeigniter 3.0.6

PHP : 5.6

Issue : When running my website, I have random logouts that happen after 5 minutes.  This means when I start my computer, after 5 minutes the session is cleared and I find myself logged out. (Random amount of time).  This continues for the rest of the day. (Random Logouts)

This does NOT happen when setting sessions in codeigniter to `files`

Setting it to `database` causes this (Logouts happen within 24 hours).

My pages use active ajax which is hitting the codeigniter system all the time.  I read that there is an Ajax Race condition that can cause it, BUT I've noticed that after reading the CI code, it's related to this command

`if ($this->_db->query("SELECT GET_LOCK('".$arg."', 300) AS ci_session_lock")->row()->ci_session_lock)`

It appears that this 'locks' during an AJAX race condition and that causes CI to drop my session cookie info (And of course logs me out under a `$this->fail()) call).  We are using the RDS system, so I am suspecting that GET_LOCK on RDS is slightly different than GET_LOCK on a true MYSQL system.

Anyone have thoughts / ideas?  And Yes I tried a ton of combinations of `sess_expiration` and `sess_time_to_update` and the only way to fix it is go back to `files`.

As I expect my system to run on multiple servers in the future, the `files` might not be desirable (If you know CodeIgniter you know why, too complicated to explain here).

Can anyone give some suggestions / answers on why RDS has an issue with GET_LOCK?

Comment: there were problems with session in the early CI 3.x versions, maybe this is the reason, upgrade to 3.1.7. I've answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48646409/2275490 maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try with an upgrade.  Though I did flip through the change logs and nothing talks about GET_LOCK.  but I am hopeful.  They mostly mention it is PHP 7 issues, I'm running 5.6