# Session lost after refresh page in CI3 php 5.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect, codeigniter-3

Try to set session. But every page reload, the session is lost

Running in CI3 with php 5.6

Following some thread

1. moving session_start() to top of index.php
2. removing `security is king`  in session.php

config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1800;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

sess_save_path return "/tmp"

Comment: what's the CI 3 version? there have been reported session related issues with early CI 3.x versions

Comment: ci version 3.0.6 @Vickel

Comment: please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48646409/2275490, please update to CI 3.1.11

Comment: In addition to Vickel's comment, upgrade your PHP version to at least 7.x (if possible)

Comment: @lauwispremium don't pit Q&A clarification in comments. Jut [edit] the question so it is a complete picture of your question with the details in one place.

Comment: I followed the article and they work fine on php 7.4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875979/codeigniter-sessions-not-working-after-migration/46876622#46876622